Using Mean Value Theorem to prove that $f$ continuous and $\lim_{x\to x_0}{f^\prime(x)}$ exists implies differentiability at $x_0$
I was trying to prove the following statement:

Given $f$ continuous on an interval around $x_0$, and that $\lim_{x\to x_0}{f^\prime(x)}=L$ for finite $L$, $f^\prime(x_0)$ exists and equals $L$.

This question seems to have cropped up in various places on the site, but every answer seems to either use the Mean Value Theorem or L'Hopital's rule. My book has not covered L'Hopital's rule yet so I am looking for a solution that does not use it, but I do not understand why the Mean Value Theorem can be applied. We have that $\lim_{x\to x_0}{f^\prime(x)}$ exists, so $x_0$ is a limit point of the domain of $f^\prime$. That doesn't necessarily mean that $f$ is differentiable on an entire interval around $x_0$ (or even on an interval on one side of $x_0$), does it? It only means that in each interval around $x_0$ there is an $x\ne x_0$ where $f^\prime(x)$ exists. So how can we use the Mean Value Theorem when we do not have differentiability on an interval $(a,b)$? Am I missing some intermediate step that establishes the existence of such an interval?

In order for a limit of a function $g(x)$ to exist at $x=x_0$, $g(x)$ must be well defined close enough to $x_0$. So this does give us that $f$ is differentiable on an interval around $x_0$.

@Nic How though? For example if $g:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ that maps $x\mapsto x$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}=0$, right? But there is no interval on which $g(x)$ is defined.

There is an interval in which $g(x)$ is defined, the only thing to note is that this interval lies in the domain, not the co-domain. It might help to recall the definition of a limit.

@Nic I was under the impression that the hypotheses of the MVT, i.e., continuity on $[a,b]$ and differentiability on $(a,b)$, referred to intervals on the real line.

If we look at the definition of a limit with respect to your problem we have: for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$. The limit would not exist if $f$ were not differentiable on the interval $(x_0-\delta,x+\delta)$ because $|f'(x) - L|$ would not be defined.

@Nic Interesting. My book defines limits in the following way: Let $x_0$ be a limit point of $dom(f)$. Then $\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)}=L$ if $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$, such that $\forall x\in dom(f)$,  $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. I can see how your definition would imply the existence of an interval. Thank you.

$\tfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h} = f'(\xi_h)$ for $\xi_h \in (x_0, x_0+h)$ and $h>0$. Then let $h \searrow 0$. Same for $h<0$.
